# Value inside input doesn't get updatet after method call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I would like to create a todo-List app. Here is my Code:
HTML:

```
<div class="divPadder">
  <input ref="makePlaceholderEmpty" class="inputBoxSize" type="text" :placeholder="placeholder"v-model="task">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item,index) in this.tasks" :key="index">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="button" v-on:click="pushAndMakePCEmpty">Submit</button>
```

script:

```
data() {
return {
  placeholder:"put your notes here :)))",
  task: "",
  tasks: []
};


},
  methods: {
    pushAndMakePCEmpty() {
      this.$refs.makePlaceholderEmpty.value = "";
      this.tasks.push(this.task);
    }
  }
```

My problem is as soon as I add the v-for part into my html code that my value doesn't get updatet to a emtpy string as it should. If I comment the v-for part out, the value attribute gets updatet. Hope somebody sees problem here.

Comment: Remove `this` from your v-for loop.

Comment: still doesn't work :/

Comment: Well the for can't run because you don't have any items in it. try adding `v-if="tasks.length > 0"` to the UL. That way it won't try to run until tasks has items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a quick snippet using what you've already made, I believe this fits your expectations.

Just try and run the snippet ;D

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
   return {
      placeholder:"put your notes here :)))",
      task: "",
      tasks: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    pushAndMakePCEmpty() {
      this.tasks.push(this.task);
      this.task = "";
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="divPadder">
  <input ref="makePlaceholderEmpty" class="inputBoxSize" type="text" :placeholder="placeholder"v-model="task">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item,index) in tasks" :key="index">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="button" v-on:click="pushAndMakePCEmpty">Submit</button>
</div>
```

The code itself should be self-explanatory, but to point out the changes I've made:

1. Removed the **this** from the v-for
2. Changed the way to reset the value from the input by using Vue's v-model interface through changing **task** data

Comment: well this worked for me but I don't understand what I did wrong (and also cant find the part that you have edited). Can you tell me what I did wrong? And thank you very much.

Comment: @quinzo I've changed the `this.$refs.makePlaceholderEmpty.value = "";` part to `this.task = "";`, and removed the **this** from here `<li v-for="(item,index) in this.tasks" :key="index">{{item}}</li>`.